# How to use Ruby and Nokogiri to parse XML

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

This document is the output from a firewall configuration. I am trying to build a hash of firewall rules. I will later output this data to CSV/console/whatever I need:

```
<table index="44" title=" from PUBLIC to DMZ administrative service rules on Firewall01" ref="FILTER.BLACKLIST">
  <headings>
    <heading>Rule</heading>
    <heading>Action</heading>
    <heading>Source</heading>
    <heading>Destination</heading>
    <heading>Service</heading>
    <heading>Log</heading>
  </headings>
  <tablebody>
    <tablerow>
      <tablecell><item>test_inbound</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>Allow</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.452">[Group] test_b2_group</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>[Host] Any</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>[Host] Any</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>Yes</item></tablecell>
    </tablerow>
    <tablerow>
      <tablecell><item>host02_inbound</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>Allow</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.447">[Group] host02_group</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>[Host] Any</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>[Host] Any</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>Yes</item></tablecell>
    </tablerow>
    <tablerow>
      <tablecell><item>randomhost</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>Allow</item></tablecell>
      **<tablecell><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.383">[Group] Host_group_2</item><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.382">[Group] another_server</item></tablecell>**
      <tablecell><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.510">[Group] crazy_application</item><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.511">[Group] internal_app</item><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.525">[Group] online_application</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.783">[Group] junos-https</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>No</item></tablecell>
    </tablerow>
  </tablebody>
</table>
```

We have the headers of the columns and three firewall rules.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

fwpol = File.open(ARGV[0]) { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
rule_array = []

fwpol.xpath('./table/tablebody/tablerow').each do |item|
  rules = {}

   rules[:name]   = item.xpath('./tablecell/item')[0].text
   rules[:action] = item.xpath('./tablecell/item')[1].text
   rules[:source] = item.xpath('./tablecell/item')[2].text
   rule_array << rules
end

puts rule_array
```

The first two hash entries, `:name` and `:action` work perfectly, because there is only one value in those fields.

If I run the code it does not print where there are multiple values. The bolded XML line shows what I am referring to. I  need to iterate over the values somehow, but so far my attempts have been fruitless.

Comment: When asking about a problem with your code, you need to show us the minimum code and _minimum_ input data necessary to demonstrate the problem, and what you expect from it. "[mcve]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get multiple element texts as Array in the following way.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

fwpol = File.open(ARGV[0]) { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
rule_array = []

fwpol.xpath('./table/tablebody/tablerow').each do |item|
  rules = {}

  rules[:name]   = item.xpath('./tablecell[1]/item').text
  rules[:action] = item.xpath('./tablecell[2]/item').text
  rules[:source] = item.xpath('./tablecell[3]/item').map(&:text)
  rule_array << rules
end

puts rule_array
```

output is here.

```
{:name=>"test_inbound", :action=>"Allow", :source=>["[Group] test_b2_group"]}
{:name=>"host02_inbound", :action=>"Allow", :source=>["[Group] host02_group"]}
{:name=>"randomhost", :action=>"Allow", :source=>["[Group] Host_group_2", "[Group] another_server"]}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. It doesn't appear to work with the example I have set out. I still have one entry/element in the output.

Comment: I updated answer's program result. What ruby's version?

Comment: It does work, apologies. I need to learn to read more carefully! Thanks for the help/answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<table index="44" title=" from PUBLIC to DMZ administrative service rules on Firewall01" ref="FILTER.BLACKLIST">
  <tablebody>
    <tablerow>
      <tablecell><item>test_inbound</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>Allow</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.452">[Group] test_b2_group</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>[Host] Any</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>[Host] Any</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>Yes</item></tablecell>
    </tablerow>
    <tablerow>
      <tablecell><item>randomhost</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>Allow</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.383">[Group] Host_group_2</item><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.382">[Group] another_server</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.510">[Group] crazy_application</item><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.511">[Group] internal_app</item><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.525">[Group] online_application</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item gotoref="CONFIG.3.783">[Group] junos-https</item></tablecell>
      <tablecell><item>No</item></tablecell>
    </tablerow>
  </tablebody>
</table>
EOT

rule_array = doc.search('tablerow').map{ |row|
  name, action, source = row.search('tablecell')[0, 3].map{ |tc| tc.search('item').map(&:text) }

  {
    name: name,
    action: action,
    source: source
  }
}
```

Which, when run would return `rule_array` containing an array of hashes, where the last has the two `item` entries:

```
require 'ap'
ap rule_array

# >> [
# >>   [0] {
# >>     :name   => [
# >>       [0] "test_inbound"
# >>     ],
# >>     :action => [
# >>       [0] "Allow"
# >>     ],
# >>     :source => [
# >>       [0] "[Group] test_b2_group"
# >>     ]
# >>   },
# >>   [1] {
# >>     :name   => [
# >>       [0] "randomhost"
# >>     ],
# >>     :action => [
# >>       [0] "Allow"
# >>     ],
# >>     :source => [
# >>       [0] "[Group] Host_group_2",
# >>       [1] "[Group] another_server"
# >>     ]
# >>   }
# >> ]
```

*Note*: Don't do this:

```
fwpol = File.open(ARGV[0]) { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
```

It's simpler to use:

```
fwpol = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(ARGV[0]))
```

Instead of doing:

```
item.xpath('./tablecell/item')[0].text
item.xpath('./tablecell/item')[1].text
item.xpath('./tablecell/item')[2].text
```

simply find the tablecell tags once, then slice the ones you want: `[0, 3]`, then iterate over that small group. It's faster and reduces the repetition of code.

See "[How to avoid joining all text from Nodes when scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594656/how-to-avoid-joining-all-text-from-nodes-when-scraping)" also.

Comment: Thanks for this! It does work very nicely too! Guess there are a lot of ways to skin this one!